# My Python code takes a string and returns upper cases in even and lower cases in odd places. Is there anything wrong in my logic?

Tags: python, string, list

This is my code, it takes a string and returns upper cases in even and lower cases in odd indeces.

```
def myfunc(a):
    s=list(a)
    i=1
    b=" "
    l=len(a)
    while(i<=l):
        if((i%2)==0):
            s[i-1]=s[i-1].upper()
            i=i+1
        else:
            s[i-1]=s[i-1].lower()
            i=i+1
    b.join(s)
    return(b)
```

Comment: What is actually your question? Does the code work or not?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to store the new string in to a new variable.

```
new_string = b.join(s)
return new_string
```

Complete Code:

```
def myfunc(a):
    s = list(a)
    i = 1
    b = " "
    l = len(a)
    while (i <= l):
        if ((i % 2) == 0):
            s[i - 1] = s[i - 1].upper()
            i = i + 1
        else:
            s[i - 1] = s[i - 1].lower()
            i = i + 1
    z = b.join(s)
    return z
```

INPUT:

```
a = "test"
```

OUTPUT:

```
t E s T
```